# Incorrect format of data sent by $.post to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, post

I'm trying to send a JavaScript Object() to a PHP file in the correct format that $.POST wants. The PHP file doesn't set any $_POST[] variables so i must be sending it in an incorrect format.

JS:

```
$('#downloadBtn').click(function(){
    var form_data = new Object();
    form_data.filepath = $("#fileName").html();
    $.post( 
        "/UpdateDownloads.php",
        { JSON.stringify(form_data) },
        function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    );
});
```

I know that changing the sent data to "{ filepath: form_data.filepath }" will fix the problem, but this is a sloppy fix because it doesn't change as i add more and more data to form_data. Basically im wondering if there is a JS function that can transform my Object() variable into a form which POST will accept and set the $_POST['filepath'] variables that i add to my form_data Object().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try sending the data as

```
{'data':JSON.stringify(form_data)}
```

Then on server side you will get `$_POST['data']`

which you can convert into object by using

```
json_decode($_POST['data']);
```

I hope this will work

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!